# CLLocationManager stops updating location in background even with flag "location" set in application properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have the problem that my app wont update the users location when the app entere in background mode.

I've read a lot about and have already set in app properties the flan "location" for UIBackgroundModes.

Even after that, my app drops the location manager in background and stops updating the users location.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: The inclusion of "location" in the UIBackgroundModes key does not preclude the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur.

Comment: but how does other apps, that keep location services awake even when theres no change in position ?

Comment: I think it wont get suspended if some activity is going on, try running a continuous NSTimer (with a log statement), and then enter the background, and see if it stops logging. I tried this with the "Background Audio" mode and it works indefinitely without suspending

Comment: `NSTimer` will alway get stopped when you go to the background.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS5 be sure to use `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`. It is the method that keeps your app requesting location services even in the background. In iOS6 you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` as `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated in iOS6.

In iOS6 make sure you add the following or else location services will be turned of when the system thinks you are not using it:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) {
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
}
```

Comment: It seems pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is very useful in my case.
I need to get user's location even if app is in background, and need to check the distance between particular location to current location and trigger notification if its greater than 100 or 200 meters for e.g

do you have any suggestion to improve the accuracy and get location in background mode continuously?

Comment: @Samir probably you should try using regions monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Using apps in background mode is strongly restricted in iOS. 
Generally, when the correct properties are set in UIBackgroundModes, your app will be called on each location update. By setting the required accuracy low (e.g. `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`), your app will be started even on slight updates of the location.

**However** after a certain time and the app was not brought back into foreground, the app will be killed entirely and location services will be switched off (the latter only from iOS 6 on). Being unable to make the app continuously getting updates from iOS in the background made me give up my project.

Comment: Your second paragraph is completely untrue! Location Services WILL stay on in the background until your battery runs out if you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Did you try that? In my case, the app is shut down after at most 4 to 8 hours.

Comment: My App (ios5) runs 8 hours recording evry single GPS fix in background

Comment: Ok 8 hours is a long time, I have not tested that length. But I have 5 location services apps in the app store, all of which use background location services. Have not tested it longer than my battery lasted (e.g. having it plugged in).

Answer (score 1):

No change in position means no location, means no event, and no action.

If iphone moves and standard location mode is set (`startUpdatingLocation`)
The you usually get one GPS fix per second. (desiredAccuracy = `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` 
 or `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`)

If location service was started by `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` then you will only get location determined by cell tower changes.

Further since ios6 there is a defered mode, such that your application will not get position changes while in background, but later all locations at once. ( I have no personal experiecne with that mode). But this also is to be considered in ios6 and higher

From CLLocationManager description

> In iOS 6 and later, you can defer the delivery of location data when
>   your app is in the background. It is recommended that you use this
>   feature in situations where your app could process the data later
>   without any problems. For example, an app that tracks the user’s
>   location on a hiking trail could defer updates until the user hikes a
>   certain distance and then process the points all at once. Deferring
>   updates helps save power by allowing your app to remain asleep for
>   longer periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and basically you have to set the pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically flag to "NO" on your CLLocationManager.